# educational purpose smartphone O/S development

Tags: android, assembly, operating-system, smartphone

I am reading O/S dev tutorial in brokenthorn.com

as like pc,

can I make and run educational purpose O/S in my smart phone?

it seems there is no Virtual machine for Android so far..

so I think I need to

make my own educational purpose O/S (for smart phone whose default o/s is android)

using exist boot loader, boot it up from SD CARD since I have very small rom.

for now, I have questions

1. is it possible to boot from my own O/S which is in SD CARD? if so, then.. how?
2. what are basic for just bootable and printing "hello world" O/S? signature, location of binary file, etc
   (I want to develop in assembly language)

although PC base learning would be more efficient, I just want to know.

could somebody let me know how?

any suggestion, simple resource, useful web site link, keyword for google are also welcome.

thanks

p.s. do I have to make my own boot loader? since SD CARD (16GB) is formatted as fat32?

thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create an operating system for android phones, it might be an better idea to gather some friends and do it in a group as it might even take years to complete it on your own. But anyways, here are some stuff you might want to check:

1) Well, i would say no to this, because android is just a operating system, and all devices running android are not same. Many devices come with locked bootloader which doesnt let you install any other custom rom or operating system without the manufacturers permission. "BUT", if you are really into creating an operating system for smartphones, go for a HTC HD2. Primarily because it is powerful and has a powerful 1ghz snapdragon processor, and also because it has an unlocked bootloader and everything. It came shipped with windows mobile 6.5 (i own this device), but "Cotulla" a developer on xda forums created a custom bootloader called [MAGLDR](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=893618) which is able to boot linux based operating system from sd card. If you can get the source code of the bootloader by contacting the developer as it is closed source, you might be able to run your os easily directly on the smartphone and debug it. There is another similar bootloader called [cLk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=901305) made by "codesmith" on xda forums.

2) For creating a Hello World operating system, i found this -> http://www.viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/hello_world_bootloader.php tutorial which might be useful. Not for android phones, but might be helpful.

Good luck :)

P.S. You will have to create a boot loader for yourself as i dont know any android device that has a bootloader that can run operating systems from SD. And you can format FAT32 to ext3/4 anytime :)